# How do I reset the appearence of a button?

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I have an active X command button in an excel workbook.

When clicked, this button changes the active sheet.

When I return to the sheet containing the button, it has the appearence of a button that is being clicked.

I assume that behind the scenes active X uses the active sheet to reset button visuals, thus changing the active sheet prevents this automatic change. Is there some way that I can change the button manually?

It is not the end of the world, as clicking a cell in the sheet containing the button does the trick, but I would prefer that this reset happen automatically without any need for user input.

Any advice would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Do  you really need an ActiveX button rather than a Form one, or a shape? The latter are much more stable.

Comment: I had assumed the buttons would be more stable.

What is a form one and why are shapes more stable?

Comment: When you add a button to a sheet, there are two types. The native Excel Form one, or the activex one. Form controls (and Shapes) are both part of the Excel library and are more stable on worksheets. ActiveX ones are from external libraries (eg the MSForms library) and are prone to weird behaviour.